# Align div to the bottom of another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align only the social media (instagram/facebook) so that they are all resting on the same row, while keeping the colorblocks of unknown height (since these are meant to be responsive logos) as they are (vertically centralised to one another).

Any comments on how to do so? I'm also working with twitter bootstrap.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72zkoxyk/)

HTML

```
<div class="row logoLocation vertical-align">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 kite vcenter">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 kiteSocialMedia">
              Facebook/Instagram
            </div>    
        </div>

         <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 supermarket vcenter">                  
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 supermarketSocialMedia">
                Facebook/Instagram
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 koskos vcenter">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 koskosSocialMedia">
            Facebook/Instagram
              </div>
          </div>
 </div> <!--row -->
```

CSS

```
.vertical-align{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.kite{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
}

.supermarket{
   width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
}

.koskos{
  width:175px;
  height:400px;
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: The link doesn't show anything.

Comment: "Align to bottom" and "centalised" are two different things. But the easiers (and cleanest) way to show a bunch of icons is to make them all the same size.

Comment: See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you provide CSS also. It can also be useful if you supply a jsfiddle or similar

Comment: @Paulie_D click on the logo, and it will enter to the page

Comment: So provide THAT link, we're not mind readers

Comment: @Andrew Hi I've cleaned up my code and provided js fiddle

Comment: from what I have seen you will have to make all the logo boxes the same height with a `position:relative;` then the item you want at the bottom needs `position: absolute; bottom:0px;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep some elements in same row, you have to divide the row.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
   // Elements
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6">
   // Elements
   </div>
</div>
```

You can divide in any combination. Like: `4+4+4, 3+3+3+3......=12`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `position:absolute;`. Adjust the `top` value for responsive screens.

```
.kiteSocialMedia, .supermarketSocialMedia, .koskosSocialMedia {
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you would have to make all your divs the same height.

You can use flexbox for that.

Then push the "SocialMedia" div to the bottom either again using flexbox or absolute positioning if the image is to be vertically centered in the div.

```css
.logoLocation {
  display: flex;
}
.logoLocation > div {
  padding-top: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
[class$="SocialMedia"] {
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row logoLocation vertical-align">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 kite vcenter">
    <a href="http://www.eat-at-kite.sg" target="_blank">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://thesupermarketco.sg/test/images/kite_logo.png" alt="Kite Logo" />
    </a>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 kiteSocialMedia">
      <a class="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/kiteoncraig" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a>/
      <a class="insta" href="http://www.instagram.com/eatatkite" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 supermarket vcenter">
    <a href="http://www.sprmrkt.com.sg" target="_blank">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://thesupermarketco.sg/test/images/sprmrkt_logo.png" alt="SPRMKRT Logo">
    </a>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 supermarketSocialMedia">
      <a class="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/sprmrktsg" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a>/
      <a class="insta" href="http://instagram.com/sprmrkt" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 koskos vcenter">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://thesupermarketco.sg/test/images/koskos_logo.png" alt="Koskos Logo">

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 koskosSocialMedia">
      <a class="fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/koskos.sg" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a>/
      <a class="insta" href="http://instagram.com/koskos_sg" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OXBNrE) (using flexbox).